# how to set the range in the colorbar manually?

Tags: matlab, plot, colorbar

I have a wide range of values and while plotting as a scatter(x,y,z), the colorbar showing the z axis shows a wide range of values, now I am not interested in the lower range values. Is there any method to change the range in color bar.
I have the following part of my code to plot, I also intend to plot the log plot. For eg. I want to set the range in my log plot to 14 to the maximum value.

I want some values not to be displayed at all. so that the color bar has a limited range, say from 14 to maximum. At present it is showing from 9 to maximum in the log plot.

```
scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1), 5, gnd);

title('G plot (m^-^2)');

colorbar('eastoutside');

xlabel(' X-axis (microns)');

ylabel('Y-axis (microns)');

figure;

log_g=log10(gnd);

scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1), 5,log_g);

colorbar('eastoutside');

xlabel(' X-axis (microns)');

ylabel('Y-axis (microns)');

title('G Density, log plot (m^-^2)');
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you want. Do you want to change the colors in the colorbar, or do you want to prevent some values from being displayed at all?

Comment: I want some values not to be displayed at all. so that the color bar has a limited range, say from 14 to maximum. At present it is showing from 9 to maximum in the log plot.

Comment: why not just remove the points you don't want shown from the plot?

Comment: how can I do that? I have a matrix (mx1) of 1600000 rows, how can direct my program to not consider those specific points among the total    points while plotting?

Answer (score 11):

I believe that `caxis` is the command you're looking for. Usage:

```
caxis([minValue maxValue])
```

Using `caxis` like this, all values outside the range `[minValue maxValue]` will be coloured with the lowest or highest value in the colormap, respectively.

Since `colorbar` and friends use `colormap`, you'll have to adjust the current colormap if you want to adjust the number of colors used. Do this like so:

```
%# get current colormap
map = colormap;  

%# adjust for number of colors you want
rows = uint16(linspace(1, size(map,1), NUM_COLORS)) ;
map = map(rows, :);

%# and apply the new colormap
colormap(map);
```

Of course, combining this with `caxis` is the most powerful.

If you don't want to show some values outside of range, that's not a job for `colorbar` or `caxis`, that's up to you -- you'll have to adjust the data that's plotted so that all values you *don't* want plotted are `NaN`. Doing so will make Matlab understand that you don't want to plot these data:

```
data( indices_to_data_not_to_plot )  = NaN;
surf(x,y,data);  %# or whatever you're using
```

Comment: yup, I had used that, but I want the color bar to show only 5 values like caxis([14 16]) i want just 14 14.5 15 15.5 16 values to show up

Comment: @rcty: Ah, like so. You'll have to define a custom colormap then, let me edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
% don’t know why, but apparently your x and y are one value too long?
x = x(1:end-1); y = y(1:end-1); 

% only plot values of 14 or higher
scatter(x(gnd>=14), y(gnd>=14), 5, gnd(gnd>=14);
```

Comment: actually its the z axis (gnd) that is hown on the colorbar...but i tried ur method too, it didnt work

Comment: Yes, this selects the x and y values where gnd is larger than or equal to 14. All datapoints with a gnd < 14 are omitted. I see I forgot to apply the same filter to gnd though. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cmap = colormap; % get current colormap
cmap=cmap([min max],:); % set your range here
colormap(cmap); % apply new colormap
colorbar();
```