# How can I change colorbar diviver in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, figure, colorbar, colormap

Currently my colorbar are divided into 1,2,3..,7 x 10^7. Is there anywway I can change it to 10^1, 10^2 10^3 ... 10^7. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use color axis sampling: [caxis](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html)

Code:

```
caxis([10^1 10^7])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my problem is somewhat with the division of the colorbar. I have a matrix which values range from 1 to somewhere like x.10^7. But the colorbar only show 1.10^7 --> 7.10^7. most of value below 1.10^7 have the same color. I hope you can help me with that

Comment: if i am right, you want to change the range of axis? am i right?

Comment: I don't know what to call it technically. Like this : We have a ruler 10cm with 10 tick, each measures 1 cm, now we want to put more tick (or different tick) to that ruler to measure 1mm or so. How about the range of axis you talk about. How can I do it?. Thank you

Comment: axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]) look at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html

Comment: Not that one, The problem is with colorbar. Do we have anything else to modified colorbar? Thank you. I have searched all around Mathwork forum.

Comment: Do we have anything else like caxis, it's close to what I need

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719470/how-to-set-the-range-in-the-colorbar-manually

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?8icj45ii64bb518. Here is the picture from Matlab. Please help me one last time. Can I change the colorbar to show like this one https://www.mediafire.com/?50kzg6g1afq08ax. Thank you