# How can I change the scale of the MATLAB colorbar?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to show a colormap legend, along the right-hand side of the figure, showing distance (meters) vs. color.

The default colormap shows dark red (nearest) is 60 all the way down to dark blue (farthest) is 0.

I want the `colorbar` legend to show the distance in meters for the colors of pixels of shapes nearest the stereo cameras.  For example:  red should be 1 m and blue should be about 6 meters.

I can't figure out how to get MATLAB to change the scale of colormap to what I want.

My code:

```
stereo_disparity_map = disparity(frameLeftGray, frameRightGray,      'DisparityRange', DisparityRange );    
stereo_disparity_figure = figure('Name', 'DISPARITY ');
stereo_disparity_imshow = imshow(stereo_disparity_map, DisparityRange, 'colormap', jet ); 
title('STEREO CAMERA DISPARITY');
set(groot,'CurrentFigure',stereo_disparity_figure);                         
set( stereo_disparity_imshow, 'CData', stereo_disparity_map );
colorbar;
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I was about to answer you to use [`caxis`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) (something like `caxis([1 6])` in your case) but with minimal research, I found your question (well a similar one) already answered here: [how to set the range in the colorbar manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719470/how-to-set-the-range-in-the-colorbar-manually)